# Why this program crashes on high value, and not on low?

Tags: python, while-loop

```
low=1
high=1000
answer=int(input(f"ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN {low} AND {high}: "))
guess=(high//2)
guesses=1
    
while guess!=answer:
    print(f"CPU guess is {guess}.")
    if guess>answer:
        high=guess
    else:
        low=guess
    guess=((high+low)//2)
    guesses+=1
else:
    print(f"CPU got it right in {guesses} guesses.")
```

When I enter 1000 as the answer the code crashes and goes on printing 999 and never stops, it happens just when we enter the high* value as the answer.

Comment: Well, follow what the code does step by step at http://pythontutor.com and see where it gets stuck…

Comment: Think about it. If `high` is 1000 and `low` is 999, then what will `guess` be after `guess = (high + low) // 2`?

Comment: No, that's not the fix, because now you have the same problem in the opposite direction with `low`…

Comment: Yes thats why i deleted that comment after trying it out. I can't really think of solution now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this loop modification:

```
if guess > answer:
    high = guess - 1
else:
    low = guess + 1
```

Explanation: if the `guess` is e.g. 500, and is incorrect (otherwise the `while` loop would end), you have to exclude that value (500) when narrowing the search interval. In detail, if the correct `answer` is somewhere below the `guess`, you don't search up to 500 in the next step, but only up to 499. And similarly the other case, if it is above 500, search from 501.

---

And if you want a safety net (input not in the allowed range 1-1000), add this:

```
if high <= low:
    print("NOT FOUND")
    break
```

Comment: That's great and simple fix and the idea about safety net is something new that I learnt as a beginner, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a solution that works:**

But I hope someone finds a more elegant way

```
low=1
high=1000
answer=int(input(f"ENTER A NUMBER BETWEEN {low} AND {high}: "))
guess=(high//2)
guesses=1

while guess!=answer:
    print(f"CPU guess is {guess}.")
    if guess>answer:
        high=guess
    else:
        low=guess
    if not (abs(high - guess) <= 1 and abs(low - guess) <= 1):
        guess = round((high+low)/2)
    else:
        if  guess < ((high+low)/2):
            guess = high
        else: 
            guess = low
        
    guesses+=1
print(f"CPU guess is {guess}.")
print(f"CPU got it right in {guesses} guesses.")
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This really fixed the problem, but I am a beginner so I didn't knew about "abs"

Comment: `ABS` is just the absolute value, the main idea is that if the high and low are less than one difference from the new low and high, then another action is performed.